# how to check the recursive path Url is in react router or not

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

how to check the recursive path is in react router or not, this

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/forget-password" component={ForgetPasswordPage} />
    <Route path="/reset-password" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

in my browser if i give wrong url (http://0.0.0.0:3000/dgdfg) it taking me to `PageNotFound`
But if I give (http://0.0.0.0:3000/signup/dgdfg) it not taking me to `PageNotFound` compontent it shows me blank page. how to solve this problem using react router v4

Comment: What if you use `exact path=` intead of just `path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your signup path to exact, it will result in a Page Not Found answer.  This is because without "exact" the page is resolving to your SignUp component, because it does in fact have /signup in the path.

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
   <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
   <Route path="/forget-password" component={ForgetPasswordPage} />
   <Route path="/reset-password" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
   <Route component={PageNotFound} />
</Switch>
```